# Imagemagick processes hang forever on Loopbackjs

Tags: imagemagick, loopbackjs, child-process

I got this code to check if an image file contains blue pixels with Imagemagick and counting them - then saving the result.

It works well, but it seems like many processes of Imagemagick hang forever on the server and are making it very slow.

Is there a way to improve this code and avoid this trouble?

```
module.exports = function (File) {
    File.observe('after save', function countPixels(ctx, next) {
        if (ctx.instance && !ctx.instance.blue_pixels) {
            var exec = require('child_process').exec;

            // Convert file to retrieve only blue pixels:
            exec('convert ' + ctx.instance.path + ' -fx "u.b>(u.g+0.2)&&u.b>(u.r+0.2)&&saturation>0.6" -format "%[fx:mean*w*h]" info:',
                    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                        if (error !== null) {
                            return next(error);
                        } else {
                            ctx.instance.blue_pixels = stdout;
                            File.upsert(ctx.instance);
                        }
                    });
        }
        next();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-fx` operator that you are using is notoriously slow - especially for large images. I had a try at casting the same formula using faster methods which may help you. So, I made a sample image:

```
convert xc:red xc:lime -append \( xc:blue xc:cyan -append \) +append -resize 256x256! input.png
```

[image]

And then rewrote your expression like this:

```
convert input.png \
  \( -clone 0 -separate -delete 0 -evaluate-sequence subtract -threshold 20% -write BG.png \) \
  \( -clone 0 -separate -delete 1 -evaluate-sequence subtract -threshold 20% -write BR.png \) \
  \( -clone 0 -colorspace hsl -separate -delete 0,2 -threshold 60% -write S.png \)            \
  -delete 0 \
  -evaluate-sequence min result.png
```

Note that the `-write XYZ.png` are just debug statements that can be removed.

Basically, I am building a mask of all pixels that meet your criteria and making them white, and making all the ones that don't match your criteria black and at the end, I run `-evaluate-sequence min` to find the minimum of each pixel so that all three of your conditions must effectively be met:

- that blue exceeds green by 20%
- that blue exceeds red by 20%
- that the saturation exceeds 60%

The `-separate -delete N` splits your image into RGB channels and then deletes one of the resulting channels, so if I `-delete 1` (that is the Green channel) I am left with Red and Blue. Here are the intermediate, debug images. The first one is the condition Blue exceeds Red by 20%:

[image]

Then that Blue exceeds Green by 20%:

[image]

And finally that the Saturation exceeds 60%:

[image]

And then the result:

[image]

You'll need to put your `-format "%[fx:mean*w*h]" info:` back on the end in place of the output image name to get the count of saturated blue pixels.

If I run your command:

```
convert input.png -fx "u.b>(u.g+0.2)&&u.b>(u.r+0.2)&&saturation>0.6" result.png
```

[image]

My brain is not quite right today, so please run some checks - I may have something back-to-front somewhere!

As a benchmark, on a 10,000x10,000 pixel PNG, my code runs in 30 seconds, whereas the `-fx` equivalent takes nearly 7 minutes.

Comment: Amazing! Worked great, thank you so much for the fast and detailled answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know imagelagick part. But for node part I see that you call next non regarding to imagemgick opertion.

```
module.exports = function (File) {
    File.observe('after save', function countPixels(ctx, next) {
        if (ctx.instance && !ctx.instance.blue_pixels) {
            var exec = require('child_process').exec;

            // Convert file to retrieve only blue pixels:
            exec('convert ' + ctx.instance.path + ' -fx "u.b>(u.g+0.2)&&u.b>(u.r+0.2)&&saturation>0.6" -format "%[fx:mean*w*h]" info:',
                    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
                        if (error !== null) {
                            return next(error);
                        } else {
                            ctx.instance.blue_pixels = stdout;
                            File.upsert(ctx.instance);
                            next();
                        }
                    });
        }
        else{next();}
        //next(); //run next hook ASAP (before imagemagick returns back the result)
    });
};
```

Comment: I was thinking, is there a way to make sure the the child_process is killed in case it got stuck?

Comment: @F3L1X79 You can kill it after timeout. `exec` method returns child process instance which has `kill` method. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal